# Android Mockito - how to mock POJO class

Tags: android, junit, mockito

Here is my POJO class:

```
/**
 * a POJO class to store json response data
 */
public class SearchItem {

    private String headline="";

    private String mDefinition="";
    private String nivURL="";

    public String getHeadline() {
        return headline;
    }

    public void setHeadline(String headline) {
        this.headline = headline;
    }

    public  String getImageURL() {
        return nivURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String URL) {
        this.nivURL = URL;
    }

    public String getDefinition() {
        return mDefinition;
    }

    public void setDefinition(String definition) {
        this.mDefinition = definition;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[ headline=" + headline +
                " , imageView URL=" + nivURL + "]";
    }
}
```

and here is my simple test trying to mock the class:

```
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import org.mockito.Mockito;

/**
 * <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html">Testing Fundamentals</a>
 */
public class ApplicationTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    MainActivity mActivity;
    private Button goBtn;
    private RecyclerListAdapter mAdapter;

    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);

    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);

        mActivity = getActivity();

        goBtn=(Button)mActivity.findViewById(
                R.id.btn_go);

    }
    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }
    public void testPreconditions() {
        assertTrue(mActivity.isNetworkAvailable());
        isLayoutValid();
    }

    public void isLayoutValid(){
        assertNotNull(goBtn);

    }


   

  public void testSomething(){
    
    //this fails
    Mockito.mock(SearchItem.class);
        }

}
```

Here is the logcat output:

```
    Running tests
Test running started
java.lang.VerifyError: org/mockito/cglib/core/ReflectUtils
at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:167)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:109)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:105)
at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:70)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:96)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:60)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:52)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:32)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1258)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1135)
at mypackage.ApplicationTest.testSomething(ApplicationTest.java:65)
```

and here is my android studio gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0+"          
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0+"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.1'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.8'
    apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
}
```

How can i resolve the mockito error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the dexmaker libs to your dependencies.

```
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0',
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0',
```

You need to include these so that mockito can interact with your dex files correctly.

A better explanation can be found here: http://corner.squareup.com/2012/10/mockito-android.html